# How to show the data I got from API to react-material datatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new when using materialUI table in react.js, I want to try using react-material table but I got lost as how can I show my data in the table, Let say I have 28 data and in fact it already show the right number in the pagination but the data itself doesn't show anything. this is the documentation link for react-material table [Check this](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#material-table).

I already read several topic about this but all of them using `tableRow`, `tableHead`, and etc.

this is my component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import { history } from '../../../../Helpers/history';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { orderActions } from '../../../../Actions/orderActions';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

// Component
import './tabledata.css';

const styles = theme => ({
  '@global': {
    body: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    },
  },
});

class Tabledata extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // const { orders } = this.props;

    this.state = {
      columns: [
        { title: 'Nama Pemesanan', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Status', field: 'status' },
        { title: 'Estimasi Pengerjaan (Hari)', field: 'estimate', type: 'numeric' },
        { title: 'Jumlah Pesanan (pcs)', field: 'unit', type: 'numeric' },
        { title: 'Harga (Rp)', field: 'price', type: 'numeric' },
      ],
      data: [
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'lala',
          status: 'Penyablonan',
          estimate: 8,
          unit: 36,
          price: '36.000.000',
        },
      ],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  if(localStorage.getItem('auth')) {
      const { dispatch } = this.props;
      dispatch(orderActions.getAllOrder());
      // history.push('/dashboard');
      }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
      this.setState({ loading: newProps.loading }); // remove the loading progress when logged in or fail to log in
  }

  handleChange = prop => event => {
      this.setState({ [prop]: event.target.value });
  };

  change(data){
      console.log("Check ID : ", data);
  }

  render(){
    const { orders } = this.props;
    console.log("test console : ", orders)

    return (
      <div className="tabledata-order">
          <div className="row item-section">
              <div className="col">
                  <div className="card">
                      <div className="card-body">
                          <MaterialTable
                              title="Daftar Pesanan"
                              columns={this.state.columns}
                              key={orders._id}
                              data={orders}
                          />
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Tabledata.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { orders } = state.orderPage;
  return {
      orders
  };
}

const connectedTableDataPage = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, '', '', {
  pure: false
}) (withStyles(styles)(Tabledata)));

export { connectedTableDataPage as Tabledata };
```

As you can see, this material table have a component like this

```
<MaterialTable
 title="Daftar Pesanan"
 columns={this.state.columns}
 key={orders._id}
 data={orders}
/>
```

As you can see, in the bottom of the image you can see `1-5 of 28` and in my console there is exactly `28 data` but the table itself doesn't show any data

[image: in the bottom of the image there is 1-5 of 28 data but nothing show in the table]

can someone help me? how can I show the data in `orders` and this is the example of the image json that I have:

[image: my data table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I can fix this problem, this answer for you who have facing the same problem with react-material table if your data doesn't show but it show in `console.log`. you must check the `field` in `column`

```
this.state = {
      columns: [
        { title: 'Nama Pemesanan', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Status', field: 'status' },
        { title: 'Estimasi Pengerjaan (Hari)', field: 'estimate', type: 'numeric' },
        { title: 'Jumlah Pesanan (pcs)', field: 'unit', type: 'numeric' },
        { title: 'Harga (Rp)', field: 'price', type: 'numeric' },
      ],
      data: [
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'lala',
          status: 'Penyablonan',
          estimate: 8,
          unit: 36,
          price: '36.000.000',
        },
      ],
    }
```

let say, json that I got have `city`, `color`, and `weight` then you must state the `column field` as such:

```
this.state = {
      columns: [
        { title: 'detail Address', field: 'city' },
        { title: 'color', field: 'color' },
        { title: 'weight', field: 'weight' },
      ],
    }
```

and for the `MaterialTable` you can just put all the variable you have like this

```
<MaterialTable
 title="Daftar Pesanan"
 columns={this.state.columns}
 key={orders._id}
 data={orders}
/>
```

and you can get the data like I show you below

[image: The result that I got]

I hope this answer can help you who have a hard time with `react-material table`

Comment: I have a question here, do we need to set the state initially only after getting the response from API in componentDidMount hook of react ?

Comment: for my case, yes, I get the response first before assign it to the state